# Symfony2, a label Token appears when using form themes

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony2.6 , and I'm trying to customize form rendering. The problem that when I put **{{ form_rest(form) }}** into the form , a label Token appears. How can I make it hidden ?

This is the form theme

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}


{% block form_widget_simple %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}

        {{ parent() }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I remove the block {% block form_widget_simple %} to test what gives , the Token label become hidden.

**Edit:**
I'd like to know also if it's correct to change the simple widget block and render inside it a label or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine :

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
//........
{%- block hidden_row -%}
<div style="display:none">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
</div>
{%- endblock hidden_row -%}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the block of the simple widget which shouldn't render a label (and it doesn't by default). If you really need to do it this way, you may check the `type` variable and do not render label for the `hidden` type. Something as following:

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {% if type != 'hidden' %}
            {{ form_label(form, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
        {% endif %}

        {{ parent() }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hello , can you explain me what do you mean by (You've changed the block of the simple widget which shouldn't render a label (and it doesn't by default) ? If the simple widget should not render a label , so where to render it ?

Comment: If you take a look at the file you extend https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig, you'll find a `form_row` block. It renders a label, a widget and errors. The `form_widget` renders only the input.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried your solution but this is the error `Variable "type" does not exist in form/fields.html.twig at line 46`  , I have added this block and it works `{%- block hidden_row -%}
   <div style="display:none">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
   </div>
{%- endblock hidden_row -%}`